# Heroku running a python web app with a subprocess call to a C executable file, not running as intended

Tags: heroku

```
2022-02-04T17:14:50.300781+00:00 app[web.1]: OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: './filter'
```

Not sure what could be wrong, when running locally on my computer it works fine, but running it on Heroku it crashes when trying to use the C executable file

Comment: How did the executable get onto Heroku? Where was it compiled?

Comment: i compiled it on my computer, and deployed it to heroku already compiled. In other words I pushed the executable file

Comment: Then you're probably running a different operating system or CPU architecture than Heroku does. In general, binaries compiled on one machine won't run on another. A better solution would be to build it on Heroku as part of your build process, but we'll need a lot more information to give clearer guidance.

Comment: never even thought of that, let me compile on heroku itself

Comment: To work properly, that will have to be done as part of your build process. You won't have much luck doing it interactively due to (a) Heroku's ephemeral filesystem and (b) its use of one-off dynos. But you might be able to confirm that compiling on Heroku generates a usable binary.

Comment: @Chris found a temporary solution for now, if you compile your program in a linux computer, it seems to work. For a more permanent solution, I'll have to look into dockerfile and such i think

Comment: Yes, that could work. [The official C buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-c) might also be helpful in a [multiple buildpacks configuration](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app).